# NSDictionary and JSON value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, floating-accuracy

I have this in my JSON:

```
{"idAlunoGraduacao":001,"semestre":2,"ano":2010,"frequencia":100,"notaFinal":6,"conceito":"Aprovado","idTurma":"Biofisica"}, 
{"idAlunoGraduacao":002,"semestre":2,"ano":2010,"frequencia":88,"notaFinal":9.2,"conceito":"Aprovado","idTurma":"Diversidade sexual"}
```

In my .h file I have this loop:

```
for (NSDictionary *dados in results)
    NSLog(@"%@",[dados objectForKey:@"notaFinal"]);
```

The first "notaFinal" is 6 and print ok but when print the second one the result is: 9.199999999999999

Why?

Comment: That's not JSON.  JSON would not have two `{}` bracketed strings with a comma in the middle and nothing outside of them.

Comment: As to your apparent question, search for "floating point not accurate".

Comment: And you may consider formatting the float on display/output to avoid that; e.g. `NSLog(@"Value: %.2f", [dados objectForKey:@"notaFinal"]);`

Comment: Use a NSObject Model Class for parse this dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **JSON** is not a **JSON**, next code is a **JSON**:

> [
>       {
>           "idAlunoGraduacao": 1,
>           "semestre": 2,
>           "ano": 2010,
>           "frequencia": 100,
>           "notaFinal": 6,
>           "conceito": "Aprovado",
>           "idTurma": "Biofisica"
>       },
>       {
>           "idAlunoGraduacao": 2,
>           "semestre": 2,
>           "ano": 2010,
>           "frequencia": 88,
>           "notaFinal": 9.2,
>           "conceito": "Aprovado",
>           "idTurma": "Diversidade sexual"
>       }
>   ]

Also, your **JSON** is very similar to a Literal NSDictionary.

```
@{@"idAlunoGraduacao":@001,@"semestre":@2,@"ano":@2010,@"frequencia":@100,@"notaFinal":@6,@"conceito":@"Aprovado",@"idTurma":@"Biofisica"};
```

Then, you says: *"In my .h file I have this loop:"*, I'm pretty sure you have the loop in your .m

In Objective-C is a Best Practice to use `curly brackets` in for loops and if-else:

```
for (NSDictionary *dados in results)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[dados objectForKey:@"notaFinal"]);
}
```

Finally, as says @Koray_Alkan, you can use

```
NSLog(@"Value: %.2f", [[dados objectForKey:@"notaFinal"] floatValue]);
```